# finding the determinant of a matrix in terms of irreducible factors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

[image]

I used a combination of row reduction and expanding along the rows to get the determinant as $\frac{1}{x}((x^2-yz)(x^2-zy) -(z^2-xy)(y^2-xz))$ however I can't seem to reduce it anymore, could someone please help

Comment: Note that you have a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)

Comment: The way you've written it isn't an irreducible factorization. I take it that you are trying to factor over the ring Z[x, y, z] though I could be wrong. If this is the case, then (x+y+z) divides the determinant, and this is _an_ irreducible factor because it is x, y, and z linear. What about the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the second and third column to the first one and then subtract the first row from the second and third row. Now develop along the first column we find

$$\det A=(x+y+z)[(x-y)(x-z)+(z-y)^2]$$